# Select distinct rows and sum of duplicates

Tags: sql-server

There is 1 table with 3 columns.

```
Table Employee
(
Id, Name, Salary
)
Values:
(1,John,10000),
(2,Rey, 15000),
(3,John,20000)
```

Expected Output:
It should fetch only distinct employees and for duplicate records of employee, it should fetch sum of salary.

So, output should be like this:

```
(1,john,30000),
(2,Rey,15000)
```

Please help

Comment: This is a basic aggregation query using `group by`.  If you are going to use SQL you should learn the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the basic syntax for **[GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)**

```
SELECT MIN(ID), Name, SUM(Salary)
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Name
```

The interesting part here is aggregation functions doesn't need to be at the end. As are usually shown in the examples.